# How can I get the number of elements in a vector in R?

Tags: r

I have an issue, let's say I have a vector which consists of S3 class instances, and I will call length() on it, the length won't return the number of elements but the number of bytes (probably) it takes.

```
myclass <- function(data) {
  value <- list(
    blabla = "simplification",
    more_data = "...",
    even_more = "..."
  )
  attr(value, "class") <- "myclass"
  value 
}

test <- c(myclass(), myclass(), myclass()) # -> 9
```

So probably results in the number of fields (?)

Comment: Please show some code to understand better the issue you are facing.

Comment: @joran I guess I wasn't aware, I have the option to use a list then